# Cant seem to understand why selecting one object selects an entire group?

Tags: modeling

coming back after years of not doing anything with blender. I cant remember the last version I used. Right now I'm on 2.8 and I have been modeling an apartment and duplicating the walls with Shift + D to speed up my workflow.

Something doesn't make sense. When I use the select tool, some objects aren't selected. But when I click on one origin, they all get selected. What is going on? Unlinking deletes the object. Make Single User doesn't do anything. Nothing is parented to anything, and I didn't group anything.

[image: cant select this]

So here I'm trying to select anything in the red circle and nothing happens.

[image: this selects everything]

And then here when I click that origin, everything gets selected.

[image: hierarchy]

And here is my hierarchy

Answer (score 1):

Well I'm a dummy. All the origins were in the same spot where I duplicated from the first wall. I clicked on all my objects and set the origins to geometry.